# Include root node in JSON output In Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

RoR noob here...  I've got a very basic app (Ruby 2.1.2; Rails 4.1.2) and I've generated a scaffold and have just the default CRUD forms.  I can enter and retrieve the values no issue.  However, what I really need is the JSON.  When I access http://rob.com:3000/books.json I get:

```
 [
    {"id":1,"name":"One Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest","url":"http://rob.com:3000/books/1.json"},
    {"id":2,"name":"The Great Gatsby","url":"http://rob.com:3000/books/2.json"}
]
```

What I'd really like to get is a "book" root node:

```
{
  "books": [
    {
     "id": 1,
     "name": "One Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest",
     "url": "http://rob.com:3000/books/1.json"
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "name": "The Great Gatsby",
     "url": "http://rob.com:3000/books/2.json"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've dug through Google and SO and haven't seen the solution.  The first, which seems most obvious, is uncommenting the following lines in config\initializers\wrap_parameters.rb

```
# To enable root element in JSON for ActiveRecord objects.
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
self.include_root_in_json = true
end
```

That appeared to have no effect.  I also tried using an Active Model Serializer as described here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers?view=asciicast.  Again, no impact.

Lastly, I've tried overriding as_json in the 'book' model, and saw no effect.

Any advice on what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you restart server after the change in wrap_parameters.rb file?

Comment: Yes, I've restarted after every change.

Answer (score 1):

`Book.first(3).to_json(:root => true)` should do the trick

Or, you need to uncommend the 3 lines

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
 self.include_root_in_json = true
end
```

And restart the server

Edit

Add the following in the Book model

```
def as_json(options = nil)
    options = {:root => true}
    super(options)
end
```

Comment: My post above was incorrect and I've fixed it.  The 3 lines in  wrap_parameters.rb were uncommented.  Could you expand on your first line?  `Book.first(3).to_json(:root => true)`  Where would I change that?  Thx

Comment: Start by running `Book.first(3).to_json(:root => true)` in the console to see if you get the correct result.

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I got: `[{\"name\":\"One Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest\"},{\"name\":\"The Great Gatsby\"}]`

Comment: I retried after shutting the console down and that seemed to do the trick.  I got: `[{\"book\":{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"One Flew Over The Cuckoo's Nest\",\"created_at\":\"2014-07-07T21:43:55.666Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2014-07-07T21:43:55.666Z\"}},{\"book\":{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"The Great Gatsby\",\"created_at\":\"2014-07-07T21:44:05.235Z\",\"updated_at\":\"2014-07-07T21:44:05.235Z\"}}]`  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually one more question: where would I put that line in 'show' inside the books_controller.rb?

Comment: I think that you should uncomment `self.include_root_in_json = true` like you did and make sure to stop your server (and also spring). Then restart it. See if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately, back to where I started... (meaning no root node)

Comment: Still, unfortunately, no root node after updating the model with your change.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Rails 4, so you can use Jbuilder:

Where `@books` is an `AR::Relation`:

```
Jbuilder.new do |json|
  json.set!(@books.table_name) do
    json.array! @books, :id, :name, :url
  end
end.attributes!
```

This will generate a Ruby hash suitable for rendering as json (or you can call `target!` instead of `attributes!` to render a JSON string directly). If you want to use as a JBuilder template, just include the middle 3 lines in your template file.

Comment: I used this in a template and it worked, but I had to hardcode the table name. I think it might be because the active record result was generated from an inner join statement, so the result comes from two tables not one. How could I grab the names of both tables used in the select? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the version of the gem active_model_serializers. I encountered the same problem but switched to a different gem version in my Gemfile:

```
'gem active_model_serializers', '~>0.9.0'
```

as well as added this to my config/application.rb

```
config.active_record.include_root_in_json = true
```

And please don't forget to restart the server after making the above changes.